# What is [home]/Library/Application Support/calls-and-messages?

Tags: library

I noticed this folder, ~/Library/Application Support/calls-and-messages, taking up almost 24GB (mostly in the Backup subfolder). It seems like it's being used almost every day, and it contains log files that seem to indicate that it's created by the OS, but I can't tell exactly what it's for and if it deserves that much disk space.

Is it safe to just delete since it's so huge? Can I change the max size of the backup somewhere?

I believe I was on the latest version of macOS 13 when I first found this. I have since updated to Sonoma.

The only messaging related app I use, outside of Messages, is Zoom, although I haven't used it in a few days and the files in this folder are still getting updated.

Directory listing:

```
Dia:calls-and-messages uncommon$ ls -l
total 6232
drwxr-xr-x@   4 uncommon  staff      128 Oct  3 09:40 Backup
drwx------@ 184 uncommon  staff     5888 Sep 29 20:18 Cache
drwx------@   5 uncommon  staff      160 Oct  3 09:40 Code Cache
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff    20480 Sep 29 20:18 Cookies
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff        0 Sep 29 20:18 Cookies-journal
drwx------@   7 uncommon  staff      224 Oct  3 09:40 Crashpad
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff  1048576 Oct  3 10:16 CrashpadMetrics-active.pma
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff  1048576 Sep 19 10:20 CrashpadMetrics.pma
drwx------@   2 uncommon  staff       64 Jul 30 22:01 Dictionaries
drwx------@   7 uncommon  staff      224 Jul 30 22:01 GPUCache
drwx------@   3 uncommon  staff       96 Jul 30 22:01 Local Storage
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff     1722 Oct  3 10:18 Network Persistent State
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff       41 Jul 30 22:01 Preferences
drwx------@   8 uncommon  staff      256 Sep 29 07:29 Session Storage
-rw-------@   1 uncommon  staff     1376 Oct  5 15:16 TransportSecurity
drwx------@   3 uncommon  staff       96 Oct  3 10:16 blob_storage
-rw-rw-rw-@   1 uncommon  staff    10989 Oct  5 15:15 config.json
drwxr-xr-x@   4 uncommon  staff      128 Oct  4 17:46 logs
drwxr-xr-x@   3 uncommon  staff       96 Jul 30 22:01 sentry
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `ls -l` as executed in the Terminal. Without actual filename details, it's going to be difficult to work out what application may be causing this. It doesn't sound like any standard OS component. Also please add what macOS version you are using and what messaging apps you might use.

Comment: Do you use any third-party apps on your Mac that do calls and messages? Like Meta Messenger, Whatsapp, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: it's for the Qustodio parental controls tool. The Calls & Messages app is part of their solution for getting at your kids' text messages. 24GB seems like a ridiculous amount of space for that, though. I'm not sure my daughter has exchanged that much data in her texts.